# Why can't I just add text under a link without it becoming part of the previous link?

Tags: linking

[image][image]I'm working in schema: Intranet Article. In the text box I had a list of links and I want to add a new link inbetween the two links but everytime I hit enter the link from above continues on. I have tried to change the source code but I need to train people on this and I want them to be able to just hit enter and make a new link and not have to mess with the source at all. So I need to know how to simply end the link and have it allow me to just enter new text/links.

Comment: Perhaps share a couple of screengrabs chris to help visualize the exact process. Also can you confirm the version of Tridion, (and SP / Hotfixes) along with the "Intranet Article" schema XSD (from the source tab of the schema) and which browers/versions you've confirmed this same behaviour in

Comment: I added the picture... "Random Text" is where I want to put new stuff. However, when I hit enter after "4)" it continues with the link, hence why random text is blue and underlined.

Comment: Also, I am using mozilla but i just got a notification saying i should be using internet explorer 9 or better.. does that sound right?

Comment: I also added a picture of info I found about the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "Text" is a Rich Text Format area field. The content of these fields can be modified by a custom XSLT associated with the schema. It's quite likely therefore that your problem is simply an issue with the implementation which you can process as a bug with your own technical people or your implementation partner.

There are other possibilities: I would look at them in this order:

1. As mentioned, a problem with the RTF XSLT
2. A problem with a custom GUI extension
3. An issue with your browser or a browser plug-in
4. A bug in Tridion

One thing that doesn't appear in my list is an issue with your templates. That would only show up in the published output, and the way I read your question, the problem is already there to see in the component pop-up.

Comment: okay so the way I understand it is that this XSLT code that Tridion uses shouldn't have an issue necessarily with how it works. The issue is that when I create a link, the code doesn't end. For example when you add a hyperlink into an email and you hit enter, the link stops there. But in my rich text feild, this is not the case, when I hit enter and I start to type it continues on with the link. So, I need to know how to trick the source into stopping the link. Or just how to make a link without it doing whatever it is that its doing.

Comment: I have just tested this with an RTF with no customisations in place. It works fine. I'm using Web8, but my expectation is that it also works fine with other versions. In normal use, you shouldn't have to resort to trickery. That's why I'm suggesting you look at the things in my list.

Comment: Okay Dominic, I will ask internally what the issue may be, thank you!